# How to define a custom function to rowClick in react-admin datagrid?

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-admin, onrowclick

I'm building an app with react-admin, I have an organizations resource and programs resource.
each program has relation to one organization.
(saved in mongoDB anf I have a node server)

I created a custom list to organizations resource.

```
 <List {...props}>
    <Datagrid rowClick={programsRowClick}>
        <TextField source="name" />
        <EditButton  />
    </Datagrid>
</List>
```

I want when we click on organization row to recieve all the programs that have the same organizationId.

the API is: https://localhost:4000/api/organization/${id}/programs

I tried to create a custom function **programsRowClick** but I dont realy understand what should it return?

the react run on  https://localhost:3000
the server run on https://localhost:4000/api

could you help me?

thank's!

Comment: I have a similar concern, whenever they click on the organization row, it should show a list of programs. I am surprised it doesnt exist already, maybe create a custom route ? so that row click goes to that route and it loads the component with all the details of organizations. 

Let me know if you found another way

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this can help you :
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#expand

It allows you to display a custom component in the list on row click.

Otherwise `rowClick` accept a function which returns a path.

ie :

```
<RA.Datagrid rowClick={(id: RA.Identifier) => `/${resource}/${id}/${customRoute}`}>
```